# How to fix: Unsafe arithmetic operation on optional chaining. It can result in NaN eslint error?

Tags: javascript, eslint

In my code, i need to check if this object, which returns and html Element and check if a className equal to "is-visible". But this eslint error is popping up. Ive tried adding conditional chaining but that isn't working.

```
  const objVisible = (obj) =>
    obj.Components.Elements.slides[0].classList.contains("is-visible") &&
    obj.Components.Elements.slides[tags?.length - 1].classList.contains(
      "is-visible"
    );
```

```
  const objVisible = (obj) =>
    obj?.Components?.Elements?.slides[0]?.classList.contains("is-visible") &&
    obj?.Components?.Elements?.slides[tags?.length - 1]?.classList.contains(
      "is-visible"
    );
```

Comment: Can `tags` ever be not set? If not, don't use optional chaining in `tags.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is

```
tags?.length - 1
```

If `tags` is not set, this resolves to

```
undefined - 1
```

which eslint considers an "unsafe arithmetic operation", rightly so.

Hard to say how to fix it without knowing what your `tags` do though. Probably:

```
 const objVisible = (obj) =>
    obj.Components.Elements.slides[0].classList.contains("is-visible") &&
    tags && obj.Components.Elements.slides[tags?.length - 1].classList.contains(
      "is-visible"
    );
```